# UnknownHostException when connecting to Azure Cosmos DB using Cassandra

Tags: azure, cassandra, azure-cosmosdb

I followed the official instructions of Azure Portal. This is my

> config.properties:

```
cassandra_host="demodemodemo.cassandra.cosmosdb.azure.com"
cassandra_username="demo"
cassandra_password="aHaplLoWhRlysBrtJWiOwB79TkqSU9PjKLu5wDeltLqys5NpR9vmtHCJrTF4ScdY69yNSWUvTUphax8RijydTA=="
cassandra_port=10350
ssl_keystore_file_path=
ssl_keystore_password=
```

Then it throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to add contact point` and `Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: "demodemodemo.cassandra.cosmosdb.azure.com"` at this point:

```
[ CassandraUtils class, getSession() method ]

cluster = Cluster.builder()
                    .addContactPoint(cassandraHost)
```

Comment: Not sure if these are your actual database credentials but if they are, you posted them publicly, and I'd suggest you change them immediately (the portal lets you regenerate your access key). Otherwise, the entire world now has access to this database.

Comment: Faked them for this question. lol

Comment: An UnknownHostException looks like something DNS related, does the hostname locally with an nslookup?  I've played with the Cosmos C* API a bit and haven't had this issue.

Comment: @rsb2097 whew! But I do see real creds posted at *least* monthly, so I figured it was worth checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the double quotes from the settings.

If your credentials are correct, this should work.

```
cassandra_host=demodemodemo.cassandra.cosmosdb.azure.com
cassandra_username=demo
cassandra_password=aHaplLoWhRlysBrtJWiOwB79TkqSU9PjKLu5wDeltLqys5NpR9vmtHCJrTF4ScdY69yNSWUvTUphax8RijydTA==
cassandra_port=10350
```

Also by default the username is the same as the first part of the host so in your case `demodemodemo` except if you changed it.

Comment: Still not working. It's corporate enviroment, so it must be some network-related issue. I'll come back later with info about the problem.

Comment: By the way, it works using the CosmosDB Emulator Docker image, but that's only suitable for development stage.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. My corporate [on prem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-premises_software) environment is behind a proxy. Since I was using cassandra, I could not setup a http-proxy (it has its own protocol). The solution might be to use [Azure Private Link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/private-link/#how-it-works). An example tutorial on how to do it is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-configure-private-endpoints